# How to create rating star bar properly?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to create a star bar for user ratings, the following image is from the play store to illustrate what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I have been able to achieve the following, which is functional as you can see, but when I look at my code, I feel like there must be a smarter way to do it, and the really bugging part is that `IconButton` hit area is being shifted up a little bit,so when you touch the actual star it does not register as a touch event (i.e: you have to aim higher than where the button is positioned in order for your touch to be registered, which makes for a bad UX) you can check what I mean by keeping an eye on the splash effect when I click on any of the stars:

[image]

```
var _myColorOne = Colors.grey;
  var _myColorTwo = Colors.grey;
  var _myColorThree = Colors.grey;
  var _myColorFour = Colors.grey;
  var _myColorFive = Colors.grey;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
     appBar: new AppBar(
       title: new Text("My Rating"),
     ),
      body:  new Center(
        child: new Container(
          height: 10.0,
          width: 500.0,
          child: new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.star),
                  onPressed: ()=>setState((){
                    _myColorOne=Colors.orange;
                    _myColorTwo=null;
                    _myColorThree=null;
                    _myColorFour=null;
                    _myColorFive=null;
                }),color: _myColorOne,),
                new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.star),
                  onPressed: ()=>setState((){
                    _myColorOne=Colors.orange;
                    _myColorTwo=Colors.orange;
                    _myColorThree=Colors.grey;
                    _myColorFour=Colors.grey;
                    _myColorFive=Colors.grey;
                }),color: _myColorTwo,),
                new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.star), onPressed: ()=>setState((){
                  _myColorOne=Colors.orange;
                  _myColorTwo=Colors.orange;
                  _myColorThree=Colors.orange;
                  _myColorFour=Colors.grey;
                  _myColorFive=Colors.grey;
                }),color: _myColorThree,),
                new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.star), onPressed: ()=>setState((){
                  _myColorOne=Colors.orange;
                  _myColorTwo=Colors.orange;
                  _myColorThree=Colors.orange;
                  _myColorFour=Colors.orange;
                  _myColorFive=Colors.grey;
                }),color: _myColorFour,),
                new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.star), onPressed: ()=>setState((){
                  _myColorOne=Colors.orange;
                  _myColorTwo=Colors.orange;
                  _myColorThree=Colors.orange;
                  _myColorFour=Colors.orange;
                  _myColorFive=Colors.orange;
                }),color: _myColorFive,),
              ],

          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

So is what is the better approach here?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Too much repetition and padding! duh

Anyway, that's how I'd do it. Simple, reusable. 
You can use it both with and without clicks (no click disable the ripple effect). 
Half stars too. And use primary color for filled stars if no color is specified.

[image]

```
typedef void RatingChangeCallback(double rating);

class StarRating extends StatelessWidget {
  final int starCount;
  final double rating;
  final RatingChangeCallback onRatingChanged;
  final Color color;

  StarRating({this.starCount = 5, this.rating = .0, this.onRatingChanged, this.color});

  Widget buildStar(BuildContext context, int index) {
    Icon icon;
    if (index >= rating) {
      icon = new Icon(
        Icons.star_border,
        color: Theme.of(context).buttonColor,
      );
    }
    else if (index > rating - 1 && index < rating) {
      icon = new Icon(
        Icons.star_half,
        color: color ?? Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      );
    } else {
      icon = new Icon(
        Icons.star,
        color: color ?? Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      );
    }
    return new InkResponse(
      onTap: onRatingChanged == null ? null : () => onRatingChanged(index + 1.0),
      child: icon,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Row(children: new List.generate(starCount, (index) => buildStar(context, index)));
  }
}
```

You can then use it like this :

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => new _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  double rating = 3.5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new StarRating(
      rating: rating,
      onRatingChanged: (rating) => setState(() => this.rating = rating),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what I should set `onRatingChanged:` to, in order to enable the rating by clicking ?

Comment: Most of the time, a `(rating) => setState(() => this.rating = rating))` should be enough

Comment: Can you clarify this please? is not `onRatingChanged` should be set to something like that `onRatingChanged:(RatingChangeCallback)=>....`

Comment: Added an example on the original post

Comment: anybody know how to implement this in cupertino? because InkResponse depend on Material. thanks

Comment: @hahnsaja Use `GestureDetector`

Comment: @RémiRousselet ow thanks, it works. But when i clicked the star, the color not update (still in default rating)

Comment: Is there any way to actually use this for ratings though?   From what I have found for android apps, any "leave a review" functionality just hyperlinks to the store front.

Comment: If you will add `allowHalfRating=true/false` then there is no need to add any dependency. It will be useful.

Comment: Tell me, if I want to disable the ability to click, but only so that the data is pulled from Api, what code should I remove?

Answer (score 9):

There is a package on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) to do this easily.

Check this - https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_star_rating

**Complete Example**

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:smooth_star_rating/smooth_star_rating.dart';

 void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

 class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 var rating = 0.0;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Rating bar demo',
    theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.green,
  ),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
        child: SmoothStarRating(
      rating: rating,
      size: 45,
      starCount: 5,
      onRatingChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          rating = value;
        });
      },
      )),
    ),
  );
 }
}
```

**Demo**

[image]

Comment: @bhargav-rao I don't understand why you deleted my answer. Its a library, I know but there is an example that helping how to use it. Please consider more on your actions before deleting another post.

Comment: So how do you actually send the star rating that a user chooses to the storefront as an actual review?   There is no point allowing a user choose stars if you can't use them.

Comment: @Bisclavret When a user selects the particular rating, the value of rating is updated. (onRatingChanged:) .Then you can send the user selected rating (rating) to any page or to your database. If you write a print Statement on rating (print(rating)) you can easily see the rating is changed. Thanks.

Comment: I don't doubt that the result is correct, but where is the code to actually send this to the storefront in a format that the storefront will recognise and accept?

Comment: It's not officially given by Flutter.

Comment: Yah. I just meant there is a package in the pub.dev Thank you for pointing it out and I updated it.

Answer (score 6):

Another great alternative is using this library: **flutter_rating_bar**. It is well implemented, elegant, and easily configurable.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_rating_bar

Example:

```
RatingBar(
   initialRating: 3,
   minRating: 1,
   direction: Axis.horizontal,
   allowHalfRating: true,
   itemCount: 5,
   itemPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
   itemBuilder: (context, _) => Icon(
     Icons.star,
     color: Colors.amber,
   ),
   onRatingUpdate: (rating) {
     print(rating);
   },
);
```

Answer (score 3):

That happens because of the height specified for the row widget. The gestures are detected only to that height. Removing the height will scale the row to fit the children, thus allowing the tap gestures on the IconButton to be detected perfectly.

I think I made a slightly better solution.

Rating component code:

```
int _rating = 0;

void rate(int rating) {
  //Other actions based on rating such as api calls.
  setState(() {
    _rating = rating;
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text("My Rating"),
    ),
    body: new Center(
      child: new Container(
        width: 500.0,
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new GestureDetector(
              child: new Icon(
                Icons.star,
                color: _rating >= 1 ? Colors.orange : Colors.grey,
              ),
              onTap: () => rate(1),
            ),
            new GestureDetector(
              child: new Icon(
                Icons.star,
                color: _rating >= 2 ? Colors.orange : Colors.grey,
              ),
              onTap: () => rate(2),
            ),
            new GestureDetector(
              child: new Icon(
                Icons.star,
                color: _rating >= 3 ? Colors.orange : Colors.grey,
              ),
              onTap: () => rate(3),
            ),
            new GestureDetector(
              child: new Icon(
                Icons.star,
                color: _rating >= 4 ? Colors.orange : Colors.grey,
              ),
              onTap: () => rate(4),
            ),
            new GestureDetector(
              child: new Icon(
                Icons.star,
                color: _rating >= 5 ? Colors.orange : Colors.grey,
              ),
              onTap: () => rate(5),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

If you wish to use you code in the question, then
Replace:

```
child: new Container(
      height: 10.0,
      width: 500.0,
      child: new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
```

With:

```
child: new Container(
      width: 500.0,
      child: new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: How about inlining the rate() method to onTap: () => setState(() => _rating = 1)?

Comment: Inlining rate method is a good idea if there are no actions to be triggered based on rating. I felt inlining rating could result in 5 edits incase of any action to be triggered based on rating. Added a comment in the rate method, hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is mine

```
List<bool> ratingStarStatus = <bool>[
true,
false,
false,
false,
false
];

int rating=1;

Widget addImage(String icon){
    return new Image.asset(
        icon,
        height: 25.0,
        width: 25.0,
    );
}

Widget addRatingImage(int index){
    return new InkWell(
        onTap: (){
            rating=index+1;
            reDrawRating(index);
        },
        child: addImage(ratingStarStatus[index]?Constant.iconStarEnable: Constant.iconStarDisable)
    );
}
void reDrawRating(int index){
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        if(i<=index){
            setState(() {
                ratingStarStatus[i]=true;
            });
        }else{
            setState(() {
                ratingStarStatus[i]=false;
        });
        }
    }
}

Widget addRatingView(){
    var stars = <Widget>[];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var star = addRatingImage(i);
        var padding = new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 0.0));
        stars.add(star);
        stars.add(padding);
    }

    return new Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: stars,
    );
}
```

Call **addRatingView** function to attach rating view

Answer (score 0):

I tried modifying a tutorial to create an interactive star rating. Here's what I came up with using a loop and onPressed **without the need for InkWell**.

```
`class RatingsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RatingsWidgetState createState() => _RatingsWidgetState();
}

class _RatingsWidgetState extends State<RatingsWidget> {
  int _rating = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> array = [];
    var filled = Colors.blue;
    var empty = Colors.black;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      array.add(IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.star),
        color: (_rating < i ? empty : filled),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _rating = i;
          });
        },
      ));
    }
    return Row(
      children: array,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    );
  }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I make a `5 star rating` helper widget based on `Material icon without any other third party libraries`.

Notes: I determine that rating less than 2 is bad so I set color of such stars to red otherwise, I set the bar color to green. Of course, you can change the color to whatever meets your needs.

Then I map the list `[1,2,3,4,5]` to the appropriate star icon given the value in the rating and return  a `Row or star ratings.`

You can quickly and easily convert this into a StatelessWidget but that is not my of high priority to me right now.

```
Widget buildRatingStar(double starValue) {
  Color color = starValue < 2 ? Colors.red : Colors.green;
  var starIconsMap = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((e) {
    if (starValue >= e) {
      return Icon(
        Icons.star_rate,
        color: color,
      );
    } else if (starValue < e && starValue > e - 1) {
      return Icon(
        Icons.star_half,
        color: color,
      );
    } else {
      return Icon(Icons.star_border, color: color);
    }
  }).toList();

  return Row(children: starIconsMap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try [rive](https://rive.app/community/search/rating/). The stars animation is using rive. And for the images using a simple animation from `AnimatedSwitcher`. This how i animated those images:

```dart
AnimatedSwitcher(
   duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
   child: Image.asset(
      _getImageBasedOnRating(rating), // return your own image assets
      key: ValueKey(rating), // you should add key to trigger the switcher
      width: 120,
      height: 120,
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
   ),
),
```

That animation will add a light fade away effect to your images, your image will be a bit blinking without this. I think rive is a good choice, because [rive files are smaller, faster, and take less memory compared to lottie files.](https://rive.app/blog/rive-as-a-lottie-alternative)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used the example of the first answer and added a drag feature. You can click stars to set them, drag them to set half stars and there is a static version as well for simply displaying a rating. The example has an on-set callback if you want to change something alongside the change in star rating.

```
Widget _buildStar(int rating, int currentCount, Color starColour, double size,
    Function(int) onTapCallback) {
  Widget star = Container();
  if (rating <= currentCount) {
    star = Icon(
      Icons.star_border,
      color: starColour,
      size: size,
    );
  } else {
    if (rating == currentCount + 1) {
      star = Icon(
        Icons.star_half,
        size: size,
        color: starColour,
      );
    } else {
      star = Icon(
        Icons.star,
        color: starColour,
        size: size,
      );
    }
  }
  return InkWell(
    onTap: () => onTapCallback(currentCount + 2),
    child: star,
  );
}

///Rating Out Of 10 but displays 5 stars which can be halves. Can tap or drag stars
class RatingStars extends StatefulWidget {
  RatingStars({
    super.key,
    this.initialRating = 0,
    required this.setCallback,
  });

  int initialRating;
  Function(int) setCallback;

  @override
  State<RatingStars> createState() => _RatingStarsState();
}

class _RatingStarsState extends State<RatingStars> {
  @override
  void setState(VoidCallback callback) {
    super.setState(callback);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _rating = widget.initialRating;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  late int _rating;

  double _dragXTracker = 0;
  final double dragChangeThreshold = 10;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
          _dragXTracker += details.delta.dx;
          if (_dragXTracker.abs() > dragChangeThreshold) {
            if (_dragXTracker > 0 && _rating < 10) {
              setState(() => _rating += 1);
              widget.setCallback(_rating);
            } else if (_dragXTracker < 0 && _rating > 0) {
              setState(() => _rating -= 1);
              widget.setCallback(_rating);
            }
            _dragXTracker = 0;
          }
        },
        onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
          _dragXTracker = 0;
        },
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: List<Widget>.generate(
            5,
            (index) => _buildStar(
                _rating, (index) * 2, Colors.yellow, 24,
                (starRating) {
              setState(() {
                _rating = starRating;
              });
              widget.setCallback(_rating);
            }),
          ).divide(const SizedBox(width: 5.0)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StaticRatingStars extends StatefulWidget {
  StaticRatingStars({
    super.key,
    required this.rating,
  });

  int rating;

  @override
  State<StaticRatingStars> createState() => _StaticRatingStarsState();
}

class _StaticRatingStarsState extends State<StaticRatingStars> {
  @override
  void setState(VoidCallback callback) {
    super.setState(callback);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: List<Widget>.generate(
          5,
          (index) => _buildStar(widget.rating, (index) * 2,
              Colors.yellow, 24, (starRating) {}),
        ).divide(const SizedBox(width: 5.0)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If anyone wants to show the text also then you can use this piece of code.
The code can work for both double or int values, i am using this with SmoothStarRating widget from here [smoothStarRating](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/smooth_star_rating).

```
Text(
    rate == 5.0
        ? 'Its 5'
        : ((rate < 5.0) & (rate > 3.0))
            ? 'Its 4'
            : ((rate < 4.0) & (rate > 2.0))
                ? 'Its 3'
                : ((rate < 3.0) & (rate > 1.0))
                    ? 'Its 2'
                    : ((rate < 2.0) & (rate > 0.0))
                        ? 'Its 1'
                        : 'Its0',
),
```

Answer (score -1):

[A cool way of rating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbs82.png)

```
class RatingButtons extends StatefulWidget {
  const RatingButtons({
    Key key,
    @required this.feedbackIcons,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<Widget> feedbackIcons;
//Here you can create a list of icons for rating or 
//you can pass the icon list while using this widget

  @override
  _RatingButtonsState createState() => _RatingButtonsState();
}

class _RatingButtonsState extends State<RatingButtons> {
  int rating;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, children: [
      ...widget.feedbackIcons.map((icon) {
        return GestureDetector(
          child: rating == widget.feedbackIcons.indexOf(icon)
              ? CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 30,
                  backgroundColor: kThemeColor,
                  child: icon,
                )
              : icon,
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              rating = widget.feedbackIcons.indexOf(icon);
            });
          },
        );
      }).toList()
    ]);
  }
}
```