# How to do random number of stars? (rating)

Tags: dynamic, widget, row, flutter

Doing a row of stars as a rating is trivial, but I am not sure what the correct flutter way of doing a random number of them?

In other words, say I have a max of 5 stars for a rating, how do I do, just one or two stars? I could have a switch statement, and return the appropriate row widget with one or two stars, but these seems to be an ugly way to do it.

Is there a proper Flutter/Dart way to do this kind of thing?

(my question is not just about this of course, I want to find the correct flutter methodology of doing this kind of thing)

Comment: I am not sure how relevant this to your question, but I have asked a similar question here, maybe it will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637566/how-to-create-rating-star-bar-properly/46645766#46645766

Comment: Will look it over.....

Answer (score 2):

By answering this question : [How to create rating star bar properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637566/how-to-create-rating-star-bar-properly/46645766#46645766)

At the same time, I gave an example of a Star rating widget that can work with any number of star (5 by default).

```
typedef void RatingChangeCallback(double rating);

class StarRating extends StatelessWidget {
  final int starCount;
  final double rating;
  final RatingChangeCallback onRatingChanged;
  final Color color;

  StarRating({this.starCount = 5, this.rating = .0, this.onRatingChanged, this.color});

  Widget buildStar(BuildContext context, int index) {
    Icon icon;
    if (index >= rating) {
      icon = new Icon(
        Icons.star_border,
        color: Theme.of(context).buttonColor,
      );
    }
    else if (index > rating - 1 && index < rating) {
      icon = new Icon(
        Icons.star_half,
        color: color ?? Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      );
    } else {
      icon = new Icon(
        Icons.star,
        color: color ?? Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      );
    }
    return new InkResponse(
      onTap: onRatingChanged == null ? null : () => onRatingChanged(index + 1.0),
      child: icon,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Row(children: new List.generate(starCount, (index) => buildStar(context, index)));
  }
}
```

You can then use it using

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _TestState createState() => new _TestState();
  }

  class _TestState extends State<Test> {
    double rating = 3.5;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new StarRating(
        rating: rating,
        onRatingChanged: (rating) => setState(() => this.rating = rating),
        starCount: 2
      );
    }
  }
```